# Using JSON-LD for organization detail as well as webpage content

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am developing a website for a logistic company. I want to include JSON-LD, but not only for the organization detail, but also for the content in the webpage, but not sure how to do this.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "url",
    "description": "description",
    "address": {
         "@type": "PostalAddress",
         "addressCountry": "country",
         "addressLocality": "state",
         "addressRegion": "state",
         "postalCode": "zip code",
         "streetAddress": "address"
    },
    "sameAs": [
        "https://www.facebook.com/xyz/",
        "https://plus.google.com/u/0/000000000",
        "https://twitter.com/xyz"
        ],
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.9",
        "ratingCount": "5"
        },
     "email": "email",
     "logo": {
         "@type": "ImageObject",
         "url": "link",
         "width": "386",
         "height": "60"
         },
     "founder": {
         "@type": "Person",
         "name": "xyz"
     },
     "foundingDate": "2013",
     "name": "abc",
     "telephone": "999999999"
     }
</script>
<script type = "application/ld+json"> {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "url": "https://www.example.com/",
      "potentialAction": {
         "@type": "SearchAction",
         "target": "https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
         "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
      }
   } </script>
```

How should I write JSON-LD for different images like if there are multiple images in my webpage then how to structure JSON-LD with organizational details as well as all the images?

```html
<video loop="" muted="" preload="metadata" poster="poster.jpg" class="responsive-video" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source src="ABC.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="ABC.webm" type="video/webm">
      <img src="./img/ABC.jpg"  />//FALL BACK IMAGE
</video>
<picture>
      <img src="./img/c.png" alt="" class="responsive-img" />
</picture>
<picture>
      <img src="./img/abc.png" alt="" class="responsive-img" />
</picture>
<picture>
      <img src="./img/d.png" alt="" class="responsive-img" />
</picture>
```

How to link JSON-LD of images and organization?

Comment: Your snippet already shows that you have data about `Organization` and `WebSite`. What is your question?

Comment: I wanted to know to actually how to write json-ld for all of the content for my website like video , images of different sections and actually how to group them all in one json-ld.

Comment: And yes if you could tell me how does a search engine knows that about video am I referring to if there are multiple videos and same about images

Comment: Asking how to group all these types is too broad. Technically, you group them exactly like you have done with e.g. the `founder`, which is a `Person`: you just connect the items with suitable properties. -- Asking how search engines *actually* do something is off-topic here, asking how a consumer (which could be a search engine) *could* do something should be on-topic. --- Please [edit] your question to ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @unor I just wanted to know how would someone know after reading json-ld that what is the image am i talking about or same for the video element.

Comment: Sorry, it’s still not clear to me what you ask. You have a page with three images. Where exactly is the problem to represent these in JSON-LD? Do you wonder which type to use? Do you wonder which property to use? Do you wonder how to connect the `Organization` and the images?

Comment: Sorry but actually I wanted to say that how to link json ld of images and organization.Example would do.Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can only provide an image for an `Organization` if it’s

- the logo of that organization ([`logo`](http://schema.org/logo)), or
- an image of the organization, or an image that represents the organization ([`ìmage`](http://schema.org/image)).

If the images are part of the page’s content, and the page is published by the organization, it doesn’t make sense to add the images to the `Organization` item. Instead, add the images to the item they belong to (e.g., [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) in case it’s an article), and then provide the `Organization` as [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher) of that `Article`.